# PHP Caching data in 'beans'

Tags: php, caching

Is there any way to cache data in PHP similar to JSF? Because in JSF I would simply create a bean with session scope holding all required information and get the information from there no matter what page I am currently on.

The website I am working on is basically a image gallery which indexes a certain folder with all subfolders and displays the images with some additional information I store alongside the image. The image gallery has about 1GB worth of images and the indexing always takes a long time, also searching the gallery means that I have to build up the index again and again to search it.

A database for the image paths and information is not really an option since the person maintaining the gallery simply uploads the images using `ftp`.

Does anybody know a clever way to optimise the loading time on this?

Comment: You could use an in memory user cache like Apcu or similar? How many files and folders are there? The combined file size of the files in all the folders doesn't really affect the performance of indexing the file and folder names, though.

Comment: I would guess that there are 3500 images and 3500 additional information files.

Comment: Ok. _That_ would affect the performance. If you don't want to use a db, then I would go for a cache instead, like Apcu, Redis, Memcached or similar.

Comment: It is not about not wanting to use a database, the problem is that I have no way of keeping the database in sync with the actual files in the gallery, since the upload is done using ftp

Comment: I would probably create a cron script in the background that periodically checks if any new files have arrived (check the modification date on the top folder) and if it has since last check, update the database. I can't really think of another way to do this in PHP.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll write a php script doing that and tell the maintainer to call it everytime he uploads files. I can not put a cronjob since it is a shitty free hoster.